Azure B2C App Always Redirects to <domain>/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/Error
I have a simple .NET 8 razor pages test application where I'm trying to leverage an Azure B2C tenant for identity. I have Azure AD B2C configured in my program.cs file, and I have added authorization to all pages so that an unauthenticated user is always directed to log in, but rather than getting the azure b2c login page, I keep getting directed to https://localhost:7027/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/Error, which results in a 404 error. Im doing this in debug mode in visual studio. Im not sure what I may have configured incorrectly, as I don't have any real experience in B2C prior to this.
Program.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

// Add Azure AD B2C authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// Apply [Authorize] attribute globally
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

appsettings.json
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://<my-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com",
    "Domain": "<my-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<my-tenant-id>",
    "ClientId": "<my-client-id>",
    "ClientSecret": "<my-client-secret>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "<my-signinsignup-policy>",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "<my-passwordreset-policy>",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "<my-profileediting-policy>"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}


Are you running the app locally?

@Jon Sowers Are you seeing this in Azure AD b2C tenant.

I got the same error while authenticating to Azure AD B2C, the error message is related to Azure AD B2C cannot find the 'b2c-extension-app` in the tenant.


To resolve the issue, you can download the extension app in your Azure AD B2C, please refer this doc to download the extension.
You can also create a new Azure AD B2C tenant to avoid the error.

I've created a sample application and successfully configured Azure B2C authentication.
Program.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();


if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

appsettings.json:
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://{ Azure B2C Domain Name}.b2clogin.com/",
    "Domain": "{ Azure B2C Domain Name}.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<Tenant-id>",
    "ClientId": "<Client-id>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signupsignindemo",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile",
    "EnablePiiLogging": true
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

I've successfully authenticated to Azure B2C.
Output:


